# How to create an IF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a lot of requests (`BursaryRequestId`). Some requests have the same identifier because they have an original and modified copy.

I need to write a T-SQL script that will check all the results if the Identifier `StatusID` of the modified version is equal to the original version. If it's not equal then change the modified version with the original's version `StatusID`.

[image: table]

You can see on the image that the modified version (`IsOriginal = '0'`) have a `StatusId` of '1' and that need to be changed to '3' like the original version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when isoriginal = 1 then statusid end) over (partition by identifier) as original_statusid
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set statusid = original_statusid
    where isoriginal = 0 and statusid <> original_statusid;
```